# Linkedin Developer API - get others profile info by VanityName

Tags: linkedin-api, vanity-url

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/people?q=vanityName&vanityName=siva-vanity-url-value

/me url is working for me, but the above mentioned link is not working on postman. Its showing below error.

**GET URL:** https://api.linkedin.com/v2/people?q=vanityName&vanityName=siva-vanity-url-value (includes header o Auth 2.0 Token)

response:

```
{
    "serviceErrorCode": 100,
    "message": "Not enough permissions to access: GET-vanityName /people",
    "status": 403
}
```

can any body help about this Linkedin Dev API.
Need to get other profile info (email at least ) from LinkedIn by vanityName.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/migration-faq#how-do-i-retrieve-the-members-email-address) is what you are looking for. And if the user is authenticating with their LinkedIn credentials, you can use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/sign-in-with-linkedin-v2?context=linkedin%2Fconsumer%2Fcontext) to obtain the email address in the ID token.

Comment: thanks for your response.

the link you suggested:
GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/emailAddress?q=members&projection=(elements*(handle~)) is for getting that developer account's email address.

But I am looking to get email address of a linkedIn user by using profileURL, those are not in my network.

Comment: I have a list of linkedin vanityNames (Profile URL's), need to find the respective email address using Developer API.

Or I need an API to find profiles (with email's) by using a specific keyword (whether it will be on profile desc/role/projects/edu/post or any). Only target is to find email/profile information on linkedIn using REST API.